# SSH vs qlogin to use all processors of a computing node

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, cluster, hpc, job-scheduler

I have a SGE cluster consisting of four computing nodes, each with 20 processors. I do not mind to give one particular user the full capabilities of one specific node, i.e. I do not mind he/she uses all the 20 processors. My question then is, should this user connect to that particular node using qlogin (through the queue using the 20 processors) or is it fine using just ssh to the node?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define queues that fit your need, but don't let users circumvent the queuing system because in that case, the queue manager can't do it's work anymore as it just don't know how that node is utilized why, how long and by whom.